# How to remove redundant data entered into xlsx file using pandas?

Tags: pandas

I need to remove redundant data in xlsx file in which data is entered using pandas. Any help on how to remove the redundant data?
Thanks!

Comment: What about https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to load your sheet as a pandas dataframe. Then use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove the redundant data. You can then write it as you want.